# Align content to top with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, alignment, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Im using GridBagLayout for placing the panels as below. I want to align everything to the top. I can manage this by using **BorderLayout.NORTH** on my background-panel (jp) but then the backgroundpanel doesnt fill the window

How can I align my panels to the top by using GridBagLayout?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel jp3 = new JPanel();
    JPanel jp4 = new JPanel();

    public Test() {
        jp1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        jp2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        jp3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        jp4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

        jp1.setBackground(Color.red);
        jp2.setBackground(Color.blue);
        jp3.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        jp4.setBackground(Color.green);

        GridBagLayout g = new GridBagLayout();
        jp.setLayout(g);
        jp.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        GridBagConstraints con;
        con = new GridBagConstraints();
        con.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3); // top, left, bottom, right

        // PANEL ONE
        con.gridx = 0;
        con.gridy = 0;
        g.setConstraints(jp1, con);
        jp.add(jp1);

        // PANEL TWO
        con.gridx = 1;
        con.gridy = 0;
        g.setConstraints(jp2, con);
        jp.add(jp2);

        // PANEL THREE
        con.gridx = 0;
        con.gridy = 1;
        g.setConstraints(jp3, con);
        jp.add(jp3);

        // PANEL FOUR
        con.gridx = 1;
        con.gridy = 1;
        g.setConstraints(jp4, con);
        jp.add(jp4);

        this.setSize(600, 300);
        // I CAN MANAGE TO GET THE PANELS ALIGNED TO THE TOP BY USING BORDERLAYOUT
        // LIKE BELOW BUT THEN THE BACKGROUNDPANEL DOESNT FILL THE WINDOW
        // this.add(jp, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        this.add(jp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but then the backgroundpanel doesnt fill the window

Why do you want the backgroundPanel to fill the window?

If you just want a black background then you can do:

```
//this.add(jp);
this.getContentPane().setBackground( jp.getBackground() );
this.add(jp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Or when using the GridBagLayout you need to specify the "anchor" and "weighty" contraints:

```
con.gridx = 0;
con.gridy = 0;
con.anchor = ...;

 ...

con.gridx = 1;
con.gridy = 1;
con.weighty = ...;
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) to understand what these constraints do. I've indicated which contraints you need to use and where to included them in your example.

Another approach is to use a wrapper panel:

```
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
wrapper.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
wrapper.add( jp );
this.add( wrapper );
```

By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout which will respect the size of any component added to the panel.